# ExtJS accordion setActiveItem

Tags: javascript, extjs, accordion

I am developing an application using ExtJS.
I have an Accordion and need to select an active item(so it expands).
`Accordion.setActiveItem` outputs the following:

`"setActiveItem" is not a function in a browser's error window.`

Second issue is that `hideCollapseTool` property, when set to true in the initialisation, doesn't do anything. Collapse tools still are being displayed.

I am using ExtJS 3.1.1.
I would be very thankful for any tips and answers.

Comment: Can you post some code of your layout?

Comment: You mentioned the correct property/method, so something about the way you are using it must be wrong.  Like Grunt said, showing code is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I have had little luck with `setActiveItem` myself. Examining it in Firebug, the accordion panel doesn't even have that method.

What I did to get around it was to call `expand()` on the item I want to have focus, 
e.g. :

```
accordion.items.itemAt(2).expand();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also expand some item in an accordion panel by it's component id like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('myAccordion').expand();
Ext.getCmp('myAccordion').items.key('myAccordionPanel').expand();
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it in a controller with a ref called *userview*

```
this.getUserview().items.items[1].expand();
```

Comment: I tried other solutions presented here, and this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.getCmp('myAccordion').getLayout().setActiveItem(0); // First Child
Ext.getCmp('myAccordion').getLayout().setActiveItem(1); // 2nd Child and so on
```

Comment: FYI, if you use the 4.2.1 version, the code is: `code`Ext.getCmp('myAccordion').items.getAt(0).expand();

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good 6 hours wrestling with this. collapse() and expand() didn't seem to be working. I'd expand a panel under the accordion and other panels would break.

Finally figured out there is some issue that happens if your accordion is hidden and then you show() it right before collapse() and expand() operations on the sub-panels.

My workaround was to never set the accordion to "hidden=true" and never show() it. Instead, I used style={opacity:0} to begin and then set opacity:100 when I needed to see it. This fixed everything, but isn't the most graceful solution.